# Setting unique Constraint with fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to build an EF Entity with Code First, and an `EntityTypeConfiguration` using fluent API. creating primary keys is easy but not so with a Unique Constraint. I was seeing old posts that suggested executing native SQL commands for this, but that seem to defeat the purpose. is this possible with EF6?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

On **EF6.2**, you can use `HasIndex()` to add indexes for migration through fluent API.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/274

**Example**

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<User>()
    .HasIndex(u => u.Email)
        .IsUnique();
```

On **EF6.1** onwards, you can use `IndexAnnotation()` to add indexes for migration in your fluent API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#PropertyIndex

You must add reference to:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations;
```

**Basic Example**

Here is a simple usage, adding an index on the `User.FirstName` property

```
modelBuilder 
    .Entity<User>() 
    .Property(t => t.FirstName) 
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute()));
```

**Practical Example:**

Here is a more realistic example. It adds a **unique index** on multiple properties: `User.FirstName` and `User.LastName`, with an index name "IX_FirstNameLastName"

```
modelBuilder 
    .Entity<User>() 
    .Property(t => t.FirstName) 
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(60)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute("IX_FirstNameLastName", 1) { IsUnique = true }));

modelBuilder 
    .Entity<User>() 
    .Property(t => t.LastName) 
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(60)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute("IX_FirstNameLastName", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
```

Comment: This is required to name column annotation as "Index"! I wrote another name and it didn't work! I spent hours before I try rename it to original "Index" as in your post and understood that this important. :(
There must be a constant for it in the framework to not hard code the string.

Comment: useful link for the problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework

Comment: @AlexanderVasilyev The constant is defined as `IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName`

Comment: @Nathan Thank you! That's it!
The example in this post must be corrected using this constant.

Comment: It's also pretty easy to create your own extension methods so you can write things like `Property(x => x.FirstName).Unique("IX_FirstName")` or `new[] { Property(x => x.FirstName), Property(x => x.LastName) }.Unique("IX_FirstNameLastName")`

Comment: Can't seem to find it in EF7 - DNX

Comment: Yeah, and how do you add unique constraints on navigation properties? Lets say if one of the `User` properties has a type of `Role`? how do you make a unique constraint off that?

Comment: That's a lot of typing just to an Unique constraint. Jeez

Comment: I believe that IsUnique need to be set to true when creating IndexAttribute in the first example. Like this: `new IndexAttribute() { IsUnique = true }`. Otherwise it creates just regular (non-unique) index.

Comment: How would you get this to work with nullable fields?

Comment: I have tried this and can compile however when I run Update-Database, the index is not added. Anyone knows why and how to solve?

Comment: @bman, check your migration scripts. I tried this on a `string` variable not realizing I needed to set a `HasMaxLength` but after I fixed this, running the migration again did not re-scaffold properly. You should have something like this: `AlterColumn("dbo.GiftCards", "CardNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
CreateIndex("dbo.GiftCards", "CardNumber", unique: true);`

Comment: @Yorro, my ConsoleApplication needed `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`. I can't run my application right now to see if it's right, but if this is OK, better add it below the other `using` statment for newbies like me ^^'

Answer (score 137):

As an addition to Yorro's answer, it can also be done by using attributes.

Sample for `int` type unique key combination:

```
[Index("IX_UniqueKeyInt", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
public int UniqueKeyIntPart1 { get; set; }

[Index("IX_UniqueKeyInt", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
public int UniqueKeyIntPart2 { get; set; }
```

If the data type is `string`, then `MaxLength` attribute must be added:

```
[Index("IX_UniqueKeyString", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string UniqueKeyStringPart1 { get; set; }

[Index("IX_UniqueKeyString", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string UniqueKeyStringPart2 { get; set; }
```

If there is a domain/storage model separation concern, using `Metadatatype` attribute/class can be an option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

---

A quick console app example:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EFIndexTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var newUser = new User { UniqueKeyIntPart1 = 1, UniqueKeyIntPart2 = 1, UniqueKeyStringPart1 = "A", UniqueKeyStringPart2 = "A" };
                context.UserSet.Add(newUser);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UniqueKeyIntPart1 { get; set; }
        public int UniqueKeyIntPart2 { get; set; }
        public string UniqueKeyStringPart1 { get; set; }
        public string UniqueKeyStringPart2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMetadata
    {
        [Index("IX_UniqueKeyInt", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
        public int UniqueKeyIntPart1 { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_UniqueKeyInt", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
        public int UniqueKeyIntPart2 { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_UniqueKeyString", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string UniqueKeyStringPart1 { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_UniqueKeyString", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string UniqueKeyStringPart2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<User> UserSet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not if you want to keep your domain model completely separate from storage concerns.

Comment: You also need to make sure you have a reference to EntityFramework

Comment: Be nice if the Index attribute was separated from Entity Framework so I could include it in my Models project. I understand that it is a storage concern, but the main reason I use it is to put unique constraints on things like UserNames and Role Names.

Comment: Can't seem to find it in EF7 - DNX

Comment: This must be out of date. It does not work at all. You just get an exception: Column 'FieldName' in table 'dbo.TableName' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Comment: You get an exception if you do not set the string length. I have edited the answer. It think it may normally be 70 characters for the whole name but it is whatever you feel like.

Comment: The code does not work and my edit to fix it got rejected. Is this some kind of joke?

Comment: @CheesusToast - post your edit as a separate answer then. Point out the differences and the problems it solves.

Comment: This only works if you also restrict the length of the string, as SQL doesn't allow *nvarchar(max)* to be used as a key.

Comment: After three and half years, updated the answer... :)

Answer (score 19):

Here is an extension method for setting unique indexes more fluently:

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration IsUnique(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return configuration.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute { IsUnique = true }));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
modelBuilder 
    .Entity<Person>() 
    .Property(t => t.Name)
    .IsUnique();
```

Will generate migration such as:

```
public partial class Add_unique_index : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.Person", "Name", unique: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Person", new[] { "Name" });
    }
}
```

Src: [Creating Unique Index with Entity Framework 6.1 fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892553/creating-unique-index-with-entity-framework-6-1-fluent-api)

Answer (score 17):

@coni2k 's answer is correct however you must add `[StringLength]` attribute for it to work otherwise you will get an invalid key exception (Example bellow).

```
[StringLength(65)]
[Index("IX_FirstNameLastName", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[StringLength(65)]
[Index("IX_FirstNameLastName", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately this is not supported in Entity Framework. It was on the roadmap for EF 6, but it got pushed back: [Workitem 299: Unique Constraints (Unique Indexes)](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299)

Answer (score -1):

```
modelBuilder.Property(x => x.FirstName).IsUnicode().IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
```