# Entity Framework: Add Unique Constraint to existing property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an existing model, `SomeModel`, which contains a property `Prop`. I'd like to enforce that the values of `Prop` be unique.

To this end, I'm adding the following to my model:

```
public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel>()
      .HasAlternateKey(a => a.Prop);
}
```

but `ef migrations` isn't picking up the change.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Add proper steps

Comment: Are you using fluent API or Annotations?

Comment: This may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892553/creating-unique-index-with-entity-framework-6-1-fluent-api

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with EF Core on an already existing model. `add-migration` picks up the change.

```
public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel>()
                .HasIndex(u => u.Prop)
                .IsUnique();
}
```

Comment: I've found that this override only works if it's there when you first create the model - not if you add it at some later point.

Comment: Hmm, you are using EF Core, correct (inferred from the tag)? I just tested it on an existing model in one of my projects, and this picked it up just fine. Maybe it depends on your EF provider? My example: https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/commit/d4c2198791e657cc20bdb3d0a51490a0d02ad9c5