# Is it possible to set a unique constraint using Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I want to enforce Unique constraint in a table & I am using Entity Framework Code-First.

Is it possible to add a unique constraint using EF 6 as i believe in earlier versions it was not possible.

Comment: See this Q -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573550/entity-framework-6-setting-unique-constraint-with-fluent-api

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It appears that the [unique constraint feature](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299) that was scheduled to release with Version 6 got pushed to 6.1.

With EF 6.1, you can define a constraint using the Index attribute as shown below:

```
[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int FirstColumn { get; set; }

[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public int SecondColumn { get; set; }
```

OR

You can use Fluent API as shown here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#PropertyIndex)

Comment: Thanks for the Update,so creating this unique index has the same effect as of creating unique constraint

Comment: Yes it will create an unique index for the column in the DB.

Comment: Can't seem to find it in EF7 - DNX.

Comment: @Shimmy [Indexes can not be created using data annotations](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/indexes.html#data-annotations) in EF7.

Comment: Why do you start naming with "IX_" ?

Comment: "IX_" is just a convention used in SQL Server. For example, "PK_" is the common prefix for a primary key index.

Comment: `IX_` is used for non-unique index, for unique it's `UX_`

Answer (score 42):

Let's say that you want to add the Unique constraint on **only one attribute**, you can do as following, starting from EF6.1

```
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

---

If you have **multiple fields** that are related to the same index then you are going to use:

> **Multiple-Column Indexes**
>
> Indexes that span multiple columns are
>   specified by using the same name in multiple Index annotations for a
>   given table. When you create multi-column indexes, you need to specify
>   an order for the columns in the index. For example, the following code
>   creates a multi-column index on Rating and BlogId called
>   IX_BlogAndRating. BlogId is the first column in the index and Rating
>   is the second.

```
public class Post 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 
    [Index("IX_BlogIdAndRating", 2)] 
    public int Rating { get; set; } 
    [Index("IX_BlogIdAndRating", 1)] 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
}
```

Please refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to define it in config class, if you're avoiding using annotations:

```
public class YourTableConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<YourTableEntity>
{
  public YourTableConfig()
  {
    ToTable("YourTableDbName");

    HasKey(u => u.Id);

    Property(c => c.CompanyId).HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(9).IsRequired();

    HasIndex(x => x.CompanyId).IsUnique(); // This sets the unique index
  }
}
```