# How to use Entity Framework code first with a table that has an unique index on a nullable column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table in SQL Server named `EffectiveRole` that has three columns

```
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DealID] [int] NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL
```

and it has an index `IX_EffectiveRole` on columns

```
([UserID] ASC,
[DealID] ASC,
[RoleID] ASC
```

My POCO class for this table is

```
[Table("EffectiveRole")]
public partial class EffectiveRole
{
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int? DealID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to insert an entity by this code

```
var context = new Ema171Entities();
var effectiveRole = new EffectiveRole { DealID = null, UserID = 85, RoleID = 14 };            
context.EffectiveRoles.Add(effectiveRole);         
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: The object state cannot be changed. This exception may result from one or more of the primary key properties being set to null. Non-Added objects cannot have null primary key values

How can I solve this? Any ideas?

Comment: `DealID` is null and is part of your composite PK

Comment: You **cannot** have nullable columns in your **primary key** in SQL Server (those columns marked with `[Key]` in your EF model) - you need to avoid this.

Comment: Does the table in the database have a Primary Key on it? An Index is not a Primary Key. From what you've shown us of the table and class, you shouldn't have the `[Key]` attribute on those properties.

Comment: A unique index and primary key are different things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837800/is-it-possible-to-set-a-unique-constraint-using-entity-framework-code-first for unique indexes. Note that SQL Server treats `NULL` as a value for uniqueness purposes.

Comment: @marc_s It is required that Table `EffectiveRole` Has unique combination of `UserID`, `DealID` and `RoleID` but `DealID` is null that's why I can not create composite primary key and using index. I have marked `DealID` as key because if there are two entity having same `UserID` and `RoleID` but different `DealID` then ef treat these entities are equal because their primary keys are equal