# Prevent duplicate record with multiple thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How prevent duplicate record when using WEB API. I call WEB API  with double click or more click and i get duplicate record in DB. Then i debugging,  pointer is "jumping" from one place to another. I am checking are record already is in DB, but its not working with multiple thread.

Comment: You need to implement transactions, locks to coordinate concurrent access

Comment: "in DB"? Which DB? How do you address the DB? Entity Framework perhaps? You need to tell us this information so that we aren't guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Get your database schema right in the first place. No duplicates allowed? Then you need to implement [a unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework) in your database that disallows duplicates. Then the situation you describe becomes impossible and the second commit results in an error.