# ASP.Net 5 DI + Custom attribute constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, custom-attributes

I need some extra logic about user's registration. So I wrote the following:

```
public class UniqueEmail : ValidationAttribute
{
    IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UniqueEmail(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        int count = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Email == value.ToString() && u.EmailConfirmed == true).Count();
        if (count == 0) return ValidationResult.Success;
        return new ValidationResult("unique email needed from attribute");
    }

}
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(p => p.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

Now how should I pass the `IApplicationDbContext` to the attribute in ViewModel class?

```
[UniqueEmail(/*?*/)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Generally, is that a good idea to use DI in the case? Maybe there are some other ways?

Comment: Yes. EF7 with all default settings

Comment: You [should not inject any dependencies into attributes](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98). Attributes should be [passive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EF7, you can use data annotation to ensure unicity of email.

```
[Index("IX_Email", IsUnique = true)]
public string Email{ get; set; }
```

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework)