# Cannot update identity column 'Index'. EF Core

Tags: .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

Like the title says, I'm getting a error message while I try to update a entity in EF Core.

Here's the entity that I'm trying to update. Pay attention to the Index property tha's decorated with the Databasegenerated attribute.
[image]

I tried to decorate wthe property so a value would only be generated when a new entity is added, but without success.

[image]

Regarding to this link: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/generated-properties.html#value-generated-on-add

And finally the update method looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: The error in the title,                                                                             **An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
      Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot update identity column 'Index'.**

Comment: Are you trying to change the identity column?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to update the entity like in the last image. I want the identity column(Index) to stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're combining two different approaches (*Fluent* and *Data Annotation*). You should stick to one of them. And when attaching your model should have a key (so EF knows what to attach to).

Either:

```
builder.Entity<Section>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Index);
builder.Entity<Section>()
            .Property(p => p.Index)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

**OR**

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int Index { get; set; }
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to change the value of an identity column you can do something like this:

```
try
{
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Section] ON");
    //Do updates
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
finally()
{
   _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Section] OFF");
}
```

There's a chance that you need to recreate that column instead of updating it.

Comment: Yeah I agree, the thing is that I was only using DataAnnotations for the property **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Indentity)]**  and fluent api for mapping the foreign keys. But since it didn't work I added the line in the second image.

Comment: I removed the DataAnnotation for [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] and replaced it with  builder.Entity<Section>().Property(p => p.Index).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); So now everything happens in the fluent API. But it seems like it doesn't matter because I'm still ending up with the same exception.

Comment: The message itself is self-explainatory, you're trying to change the value of an identity column. The question is what's changing it. Is there anything in your code before SaveChanges()? Can you debug and check the value of Index before SaveChanges()?

Comment: But should'nt .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); take care of this?

Comment: Another question, is it possible to update a column that's being generated with **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Indentity)]**? If so, how?

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried it. But the point is that you shouldn't. By setting it to identity you let the db manage that column. And I really don't see a scenario when I want to change the value of the primary key. It will most likely also cause violations to your constraints. Have you set your primary key? It didn't show in your code. That could be the reason for the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113149/discussion-between-smoksnes-and-carl91).

Answer (score 2):

For those who run into this, it was a bug with EF Core 1.0.  See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6426.

It has been marked as fixed in EF Core 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too!! I tried to add an annotation [Key, Column(Order = 1)] for my property, but it doesn't work.

Try the method below. I use it to fix my problem (.Net Core and EF Core 1.1.1)

1.Please add these code in your **Context.cs**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   // Adding the code below tells DB "NumericId is an AlternateKey and don't update".
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasAlternateKey(x => x.Index ).HasName("IX_Index");
}
```

2. In **PackageManager** window, execute **update-datebase**

Ref:

[[Stackoverflow] Unique Key Constraints For Multiple Columns In EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework)

[[MSDN] Alternate Keys (Unique Constraints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/unique-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of EF Core you're using, but you might find success with this SO answer:
[cannot update identity column in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176018/cannot-update-identity-column-in-entity-framework-core)

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Type>().Property(u => u.Property).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```