# Cannot update identity column in Entity Framework Core since upgrading to .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

Since upgrading to .Net Core 3.1, one of my entities throws an error if I try to update it with the error 'cannot update identity column in Entity Framework Core'. This happens in the attached or the detached state.

Here is my fluent config

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderStatus>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("OrderStatus");
                b.HasKey(e => e.OrderStatusId);
                b.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.OrderId }); //CompositeKey
                b.Property(e => e.OrderStatusId).UseIdentityColumn();
            });
```

I fetch the entity and update a value (not the OrderStatusId) and call save and thats when it blows up.

```
var orderStatus = _context.OrderStatus.FirstOrDefault();
orderStatus.Total = 500;
_context.Entry(OrderStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I came across this old thread [cannot update identity column in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176018/cannot-update-identity-column-in-entity-framework-core/42907267) which mentions a 'fix' of adding

`b.Property(e => e.OrderStatusId).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);`

This indeed does work, but I have no idea why this would be needed. This is the only Table in my application that seems to want this.

FYI, I was previous running on EF core 3.0 and tried upgrading to 3.1.3 but this makes no difference.

Should I be adding this to all of my fluent definitions now?

Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This indeed does work, but I have no idea why this would be needed. This is the only Table in my application that seems to want this.
>
> Should I be adding this to all of my fluent definitions now?

This is needed only for identity columns which are *not* the primary key (PK) of the table (or `Key` in EF Core).

Which should be rare - this is why you have issue only with that table.

But do you really need a composite PK (and what's the purpose of the identity column then)? Note that as for any fluent calls, the last `HasKey` (EF Core fluent API for defining the PK) wins, i.e. here

```
b.HasKey(e => e.OrderStatusId);
b.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.OrderId }); //CompositeKey
```

the line

```
b.HasKey(e => e.OrderStatusId);
```

has no effect, thus by default is eligible for updating. But then why it is here? May be the intention was to have identity PK and composite [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys)? In other words, if the config was

```
b.HasKey(e => e.OrderStatusId);
b.HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.OrderId }); //CompositeKey
```

then you won't have such issue and won't need to configure `AfterSaveBehavior`.

And if you really want a composite PK, then remove the misleading

```
b.HasKey(e => e.OrderStatusId);
```

line and use the `SetAfterSaveBehavior` solution.

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense. I believe I do need a composite key in my situation. (there could be an Order with multiple CompanyId's so a each order would generally have a few rows). When I try your change, it does indeed work BUT OrderID gets set as a FK but CompanyID is just set to not null. (The constrains does have a constrain with OrderID_CompanyID though). Is this expected behaviour of a composite key?

Comment: Alternate keys in databases are called unique keys. I don't expect FK relationship changes, may be there is something in your model which requires explicitly mapping `CompanyID` as FK. I can't tell exact w/o seeing the whole model. But that wasn't the main point, just the line `b.HasKey(e => e.OrderStatusId);` was suspicious.