# Updating a record that has a Guid primary key and another column that is Identity specification

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an app that uses a database that is scaffolded to EF using the following command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;Trust Server Certificate=true" 
       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Entities -f --no-onconfiguring
```

When it generates the entities, the table in question has the following set:

```
entity.Property(e => e.RecNo).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

The problem comes when I try to update records for this table.

I get an error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot update identity column 'RecNo'.

It would seem that the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` setting would apply during updates as well adds, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Is there something else, preferably during scaffolding, that I could add to make it work?

Comment: Show your code how you are loading the record and modifying it. Usually the problem is how you are using EF not so much how it is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
ValueGeneratedOnAdd().Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

Comment: This is what I ultimately did.  Do you know of a way for this to happen automatically when the database is scaffolded?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176018/cannot-update-identity-column-in-entity-framework-core looks it could be a missing feature from scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

When I received this error in EF 8, I fixed it by marking the column as an alternate key:

```
entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.RecNo);
```