# Requiring Unique Values in Entity Framework among items that share a common property value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am trying to make the `AnswerString` required to be unique among answers that share the same `ModuleID` value. How would I go about achieving this?

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(25)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public string AnswerString { get; set; }
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    public int PictureCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you're using a database, and if so, Can you just check for the occurence of that value in the DB? `var item = context.Model.Where(x => x.ModuleID == SomeModuleID && x.AnswerString == someAnswerString).ToList(); if(item.Count > 0) { /* item exists */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attribute to AnswerString:

```
[Index("IX_AnswerStringModuleId",2,IsUnique = true)]
```

Then add this attribute to ModuleId:

```
[Index("IX_AnswerStringModuleId",1, IsUnique = true)]
```

Basically this sets up a unique constraint where the combo of ModuleId and AnswerString must be unique.

See this answer as well: [Unique Key constraints for multiple columns in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making an attribute for the property which would evaluate at the class or property level. This would apply your business logic within the object/model and not rely on EF. If your intent is not to do as such, then I recommend the attributes suggested above or applying a constraint on the table itself.