# Entity Framework not using my foreign key but generating a new column instead

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using the Fluent API and a code-first approach for defining the schema. I wonder why the migration is generating a new column instead of using the defined foreign key. Thus, the `DbSet` is not linking correctly.

I am following this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

The relationship looks like this: server-players (parent-child)

**Player.cs**

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    public Universe Server { get; set; }
}
```

**Universe.cs** (Server)

```
public class Universe
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }

        public List<Planet> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
}
```

**PlayerConfiguration.cs** (Fluent API)

```
public class PlayerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Player")
            .HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.PlayerId, e.ServerId });
        builder.HasOne<Universe>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ServerId);
    }
}
```

The database script generated by EF:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Player] 
(
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ServerId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [ServerId1]  INT            NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Player] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [AK_Player_PlayerId_ServerId] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([PlayerId] ASC, [ServerId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Player_Universe_ServerId1] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ServerId1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Universe] ([Id])
);

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Player_ServerId]
ON [dbo].[Player]([ServerId] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Player_ServerId1]
ON [dbo].[Player]([ServerId1] ASC);
```

So when I call `context.Universes.Players.Add(...some players...)` and `context.SaveChanges()`. The ServerIds will save to `ServerId1` and keeping default in `ServerId` column. When I try to query the data from the database, no Players will be found.

I realized that the AK is using the `ServerID` as junction while the FK is using `ServerId1` when I am typing the question. However, I will need to setup a composite unique key that identifies each player has only one ID in the server. The `Id` column is a system generated one. While `PlayerId` is captured from different servers. The `PlayerId` can be duplicated across server.

I design the system to generate a new `Id` too as it is linked to the system frequently for other purposes. It will waste time to link a composite key every time it is called.

I got the sample of defining a unique key from [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896518/4444304) suggesting that I can use Alternate Key. Is this actually not true? Or I actually am not defining the FK correctly?

---

**Updated 12/01/2018**
`PlayerId` is in `Player` class instead of `Universe` class. That was just mistake while copying.

`.WithMany(u => u.Players)` generates the same result as `.WithMany()` as suggested in the comment. Migration file has blank `Up`/`Down` too.

Comment: Player or Planet?  Does Player have Id and PlayerID?  The explanation for the Alternate Key is confusing.  Can you clarify the relationships and produce a complete example of the issue you are facing?

Comment: This usually happens with incorrect relationship navigation property mapping. Check out `HasOne` /`WithMany` - you seem to have navigation properties, hence you have to specify them (eg. something like `HasOne(e => e.Server).WithMany(e => e.Players)`)

Comment: David - Oh, sorry for the confusion. I copied the code partially. Should be Player. It also have another List of Planet in the class. Thanks

Comment: @IvanStoev - I have tried adding `.WithMany(e => e.Players)` and run the migration before. But it gives an empty migrations result, so I was not awared.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - The `Id` is the identity column while `PlayerId` is the result from an external server. `PlayerId` is the column that bonds to the `Server`. And `Id` is just for generating FKs in the system. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and Answers contributed by the community.
The answer to the final goal is actually way more low level then the question asked.

**The `Players` List did not pull up because of Lazy Loading.**
That is solved by adding `context.Universes.Include(u => u.Players)` to the loading script.

---

However, it is interesting finding about the multiple FK being generated too. I will cover this below in depth.

**Update 1 - 14/01/2018**
The correct way to call the Fluent API is

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.Server).WithMany(u => u.Players).HasForeignKey(e => e.ServerId)
```

As Ivan suggested in the comment that

> `.HasOne<Universe>()` is telling EF that the relationship does not have reference navigation property in Player class, hence when it discovers Player.Server navigation property, it creates another one-to-many relationship.

---

<s>I wonder it is a bug with the Fluent API.</s> The Data Annotations method suggested works perfectly by adding

```
//To Universe Class
[InverseProperty("Server")]
public List<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();

//To Player Class
public int ServerId { get;set; }
[ForeignKey("ServerId")]
public Universe Server { get; set; }
```

It turns out that if I use the Fluent API

```
builder.HasOne<Universe>()
    .WithMany(u => u.Players)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ServerId);
```

It will generate the Relationship twice. <s>I wonder if `InverseProperty` is required in Fluent API as the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) did not say so.</s>

I have also tried the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212017/4444304) suggested by @rufus-lobo saying that the navigation name should be kept by EF. But it is still generating the FK column twice when using Fluent API.

It is observed that `ServerId` is nullable and `ServerId1` is required. My guess is that:

1. Universe has `List<Player>`. But it is not specified in the Fluent API that Player must be attached to a server. The first `ServerID` is created to maintain the relationship.
2. When EF looks into `Player` later. The relationship of `Player` to `Universe` comes in. The second `ServerId1` is then used to keep the 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: Check out my comment under the question. The fluent API should be `HasOne(e => e.Server)`. While `HasOne<Universe>()` is telling EF that the relationship does not have reference navigation property in `Player` class, hence when it discovers `Player.Server` navigation property, it creates **another** one-to-many relationship. Same for collection navigation properties. If you don't use the correct fluent API overloads, the unmapped navigation properties will create additional relationships.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Oh! That's the correct answer! I missed out that `HasOne(e => e.Server)` part. Thanks so much for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

EF Core assumes foreign keys to have the format <Classname>Id.
Try the following:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int UniverseId { get; set; }
    public Universe Universe { get; set; }
}

public class Universe
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; } // I think you can do without this.
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public List<Planet> Planets { get; set; } = new List<Planet>();
}
```

Comment: There is also a convention for navigation name + principal PK. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962).  The Universe reference is not the issue.