# Understanding Entity framework's Many to Many relationships. Why does my code crash once I try to add more data to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a join table that combines the Employee and Tractor table to record each time an Employee is assigned/unassigned a truck. I am able to record an initial employeeID and truckId but the code crashes once I try to record  second of employeeID and truckID on a different time and Day. Thus, the Datetime object is always unique.

*This is the error it shows:*

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DriverTractorsAssignmentHistory'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DriverTractorsAssignmentHistory'. The duplicate key value is (1, 2).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Using a Many to many relationship was the one solution I could think of to capture each time an employee is assigned a truck. Pls show me a better solution if you have one

```
 public class Employee
 { 
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? TractorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Tractor Tractor { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory>DriverTractorAssignmentHistories { get; set; }
 }

public class Tractor
{
    public int TractorID { get; set; }
    public string TruckNumber {get; set;}
    public string Status { get; set; } 
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory> DriverTractorAssignmentHistories { get; set; }

    public Tractor()
    {
        Status = "Available";
    }
}


public class TrailerOrderDbContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory> DriverTractorsAssignmentHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tractor> Tractors { get; set; }

    public TrailerOrderDbContext(DbContextOptions<TrailerOrderDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }  

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory>().HasKey(co => new { co.EmployeeId, co.TractorId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Driver)
        .WithMany(c => c.DriverTractorAssignmentHistories)
        .HasForeignKey(trac => trac.TractorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory>()
        .HasOne(trac => trac.Tractor)
        .WithMany(c => c.DriverTractorAssignmentHistories)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Create a DateTime field on DriverTractorAssignmentHistory and make it part of the key, so the combination of the three fields should be unique when inserting.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `DriverTractorAssignmentHistory` class?

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line of code in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`beause this line of code prevents duplicate data entry and prevents `many-to-many` mapping:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory>()
        .HasKey(co => new { co.EmployeeId, co.TractorId });
```

Or modify as below if in case `unique key` is needed:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<DriverTractorAssignmentHistory>()
      .HasKey(co => new { co.EmployeeId, co.TractorId, co.AssignTimestamp };
```

Comment: While this solves the error, I don't think it's a good answer. OP should define a unique key, meaning it should also contain the datetime of when this was added

Comment: For making unique key you may refer this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework`. But in this case the `unique key` should be combination of more than one column.
My recommendation would be to put `EmployeeId` and TractorId ` as unique key.

Comment: EmployeeId and TractorId already have to be unique in `DriverTractorAssignmentHistory` since they are part of the key, but they aren't unique enough since OP can assign/de-assign a employee of a tractor multiple times a day, so it will fail. What he needs is another field to make it unique. So `.HasKey(co => new { co.EmployeeId, co.TractorId, co.AssignTimestamp }

Comment: @jpgrassi Thanks. Modified my answer as per your suggestion.