# Insert data into table which have as part of primary key foreign key - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to write into a table which has primary key from two parts. One of them is foreign primary key from another table. I am able to create this table, but not insert into.

I am using Entity Framework 6.4.0

My db is created by this code:

```
class School
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
}

class Classroom
{
      [Key]
      [Column(Order = 0)]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Key]
      [Column(Order = 1)]
      [ForeignKey("School")]
      public int SchoolId { get; set; }
      public School School { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
}

class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
      public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
}
```

How can I insert data into the `Classrooms` table? I tried this (school with name: `schoolName` is in db):

```
var context = new TestDbContext();`

var school = context.Schools.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "SchoolName");
context.Classrooms.Add(new Classroom() {Name = "5B", School = school});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Result of this code was this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Classrooms' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: I think what you were after is a unique key, which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework) has solutions for. It sounds like your table was generated with `SchoolId` set to be an identity column, which means you can't insert values (unless, as the error notes, you set IDENTITY_INSERT ON in the query, which EF doesn't do by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears one of the two columns in your table `Classroom` which make up the primary key is an `IDENTITY` column - I'm guessing, it's `Id`.

You need to decorate that column with a data annotation to tell EF that this is an Identity column and you won't be providing any value for it:

```
class Classroom
{
      [Key]
      [Column(Order = 0)]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      ....
}
```

This should solve your problem. **BUT**: if this is an Identity column - then **WHY** did you create a compound PK together with `SchoolId` at all? This seems totally unnecessary, since that `Id` column alone is already your PK - it uniquely and reliably identifies eac and every single row in your table.....

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is [ExecuteStoreCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Objects_ObjectContext_ExecuteStoreCommand_System_String_System_Object___).

public int ExecuteStoreCommand (string commandText, params object[] parameters);

Try this before adding records to `Classrooms`:

```
context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Classrooms] ON");
```

Answer (score 0):

By default EF treats `Id` properties as `identity` column. As @marc_s noted, there's no sense in having compound key with identity column, so if your `Id` column is *not* identity column, then you need to explicitly say about it:

```
class Classroom
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...other properties..
}
```