# EF Core: Create Unique Constraint for Two Columns, Any Order

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two columns in one table, `Rates`:

```
ZonePointAId
ZonePointBId
```

With a foreign key on both of the columns that reference a single `ZoneId` column in the `Zones` table.  I'd like to enforce a constraint regardless of the order the values are found. (The rate between the zones is the same regardless of which is listed first) For example:

```
ZonePointAId = 63, ZonePointBId = 64  - Pass!
ZonePointAId = 63, ZonePointBId = 63  - Pass!
ZonePointAId = 64, ZonePointBId = 63  - Fail!
```

I've tried the solutions listed here in this [Unique Key constraints for multiple columns in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework) but they all allow the inverses to be inserted. I'm using Postgres (RDS if it matters). .NET Core 3.1.

I am trying to avoid duplicating the data for every inverse source/dest combination. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm not even sure the database is capable of such a thing, much less EF Core of defining via annotations or Fluent, but I figured if anyone knew it would be you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Well at least at the database level, you can create an unique index based on expressions. In this case use the least and greatest functions to 'order' the values:

```
create unique index AidBid_sameas_BidAid
    on rates (least(ZonePointAId,ZonePointBId), greatest(ZonePointAId,ZonePointBId));
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c7dde4268c056e579fc7552d61ae02d4);

Comment: This solution absolutely solved the most important portion of my question - the database constraint. Thank you for taking the time to comment!